# Can windows DNS server be configured to return a fully qualified DNS alias?

Tags: windows, internal-dns, fqdn, microsoft-edge

**Problem**

We have a 3rd party web app installed on a windows server. There is an alias DNS record setup so that user can type in to a web browser the app name i.e. "testapp" and get the site. This works well in Chrome browser but does not work as well with Edge Chromium browser. Edge Chromium does not see the web app as a local server so does not trust it to send domain credentials. In Edge browser users are forced to login each time they use the web app whilst if you use Chrome you are auto logged in. In Edge if you use the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) for the alias  such as "testapp.exampledomain.com" Edge browser see's this as a local network server, trusts it, sends the credentials and auto logs the users in. This behaviour was not seen in previous version of Edge.

**Desired outcome**

Is there a way to configure windows DNS so that when users type in "testapp" it returns the value "testapp.exampledomain.com" for the user?

**Other factors**

- We have tried editing the web app web server (it is 3rd part and was
  using Apache tomcat ) to redirect queries to FQDN address if not from
  FQDN address however this is not supported by the vendor and lead to other
  issues where users had to reload the page after opening website.
- Edge chromium browser configuration is managed centrally using group
  policy and cannot be changed as it will affect other apps.
- Edge chromium is the only supported browser by the organisation with
  chrome no longer being installed on new computers so we can no longer
  recommend user use chrome.
- Vendor supports Edge chromium but says this issue is a problem with
  our network configuration and  will not help any more.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to configure windows DNS so that when users type in "testapp" it returns the value "testapp.exampledomain.com" for the user?

No, as this is not a Server-Side setting.

Searching for a name in different DNS zones is a Client-Side "DNS Suffix search" decision. Plain hostnames are never sent to the DNS, so DNS can't do anything about that. Imaging a host "first" and a DNS that has host "first" in it's zone example.com *and* example2.com - which one should be returned? (The argument "there is just one zone" doesn't count on the internet these days).

You will have to provide a DNS Suffix search list on your clients (which your AD admins will hate you for) or -preferably- just use the FQDN like on any other website. This would make the use of TLS possible, enable the Zone-Model correctly, has no problems with double hostnames ...

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking your problem might be internet zones, and trusted sites when I found this article explaining the changes in browser behaviour -
[Security Zones in Edge](https://textslashplain.com/2020/01/30/security-zones-in-edge/)

Your machines are already resolving DNS correctly.

I agree the correct solution was the URL re-write, and would suggest some further pressure on your app vendor or, other than that re-educating your users to use the fully qualified address and / or pushing out updated bookmarks or links to assist them.